# Platinum-sw In Polymer Starter Kit- Nothing in browser cache/local storage

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using the polymer starter kit, I am having a issue with getting the `platinum-sw-register` and `platinum-sw-cache` to work. When I look in dev tools under resources I see no key values for local storage, cache, etc.

I did everything I was supposed to.... I uncommented the html imports in elements.html, used the code in index.html(minus the toaster notifications), made sure the gulp default task included cache config.

Here is the `dist/cache-config.json`:

```
{"cacheId":"wedding","disabled":false,"precache":["index.html","./","bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js","elements/elements.html","scripts/app.js","styles/app-theme.html","styles/main.css","styles/shared-styles.html"],"precacheFingerprint":"c546b3ce132d015b719d026e646c1"}
```

---

Here is the index.html:

```
    <platinum-sw-register auto-register
                          clients-claim
                          skip-waiting
                          base-uri="bower_components/platinum-sw/bootstrap">
      <platinum-sw-cache default-cache-strategy="fastest"
                         cache-config-file="cache-config.json">
      </platinum-sw-cache>
    </platinum-sw-register>
  </template>
```

---

Here is my elements.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-cache.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-register.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this will only work for https and not non https. To trouble shoot, I used `on-service-worker-error="displayInstalledToastError"` in which I saw `"SecurityError: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)."`.